# Percentage of a specific status type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to put together some `jQuery` charts, to represent the percentage numbers of a give message status within my system. For, exmaple 10% of all messages have not been read etc.

I can use this get a data set of all the messages, for each type:

```
SELECT MessageStatus, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() As Percentage
FROM TableA
group by MessageStatus
```

which produces:

```
   2 7
   3 84
   5 7
```

So, 7% of all messages are of message type 2 etc etc.

Now, as soon as I put in a where clause, whether this being a specific messageStatus, or a date range, it always returns the messageStatus at 100%. For example

```
SELECT MessageStatus, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() As Percentage
FROM TableA
WHERE MessageStatus = '3'
group by MessageStatus
```

Is it possible to get a percentage of all messages at a specific message Type? with Message Type, being an int from 1-10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a subquery:

```
select * 
from (
  select MessageStatus, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() As Percentage
  from TableA
  group by MessageStatus
) t
where messagestatus = '3'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a86a4/3)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT MessageStatus,
       count(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from TableA)
FROM TableA
WHERE MessageStatus = '3'
GROUP BY MessageStatus;
```